# For loops with user input on Python

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

Hello I'm learning how to parse HTML with BeautifulSoup. I would like to know if it is possible to use a user input in a for loop, as:

```
for (user input) in A
```

As `A` is a list of links so the user can choose to go for a link, using an input.

And then I use `urllib` to open that link and repeat the process.

Comment: Wait, you want the user to select a link from a list of links? That's not going to work via a `for` loop, as that just iterates over the elements.

Comment: Having a list of links, I want the user to digit a postion, and with that number open the link in that position

Comment: What does that have to do with parsing HTML?

Comment: @karlson I'm learning on Coursera, and I have to do this in one Assignement

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

choice = ''
for url in urls:
    print('Go to {}?'.format(url))
    decision = input('Y/n ')
    if decision == 'Y':
        choice = url
        break

if choice:
    r = urllib2.urlopen(choice).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
    # do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't exactly clear to me if you really wanted to "open" the link in a browser, so I included some code to do that. Is this maybe what you wanted from "digit a position"?

tl;dr

```
print("Which URL would you like to open?"
    " (Please select an option between 1-{})".format(len(A)))
for index, link in enumerate(A):
    print index+1, link
```

Full:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import webbrowser


A = [
    'https://www.google.com',
    'https://www.stackoverflow.com',
    'https://www.xkcd.com',
]

print("Which URL would you like to open?"
    " (Please select an option between 1-{})".format(len(A)))
for index, link in enumerate(A):
    print index+1, link

_input = input()

try:
    option_index = int(_input) - 1
except ValueError:
    print "{} is not a valid choice.".format(_input)
    raise
try:
    selection = A[option_index]
except IndexError:
    print "{} is not a valid choice.".format(_input)
    raise

webbrowser.open(selection)
response = requests.get(selection)
html_string = response.content
# Do parsing...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I achieved a solution on this.

Created two variables: `count = input()` and `postion = input()`

The count I have used in a for loop: `for _ in range(c)` - with this I can made a process repeat the number of times that the user want (on this assignement is 4).

The position (that for this assignement is predefined on 3), I use for list index, in a list with all url. So for open the url in position 3 I have:

`url = links[p-1]` (-1 for the reason that user inputs 3, but the list index starts with 0 (0,1,2...)

And then I can use `urllib.request.urlopen.read()`